# Efficiently covering a finite set of points in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ by fixed size, axis-aligned cubes?

Tags: approximation, set-cover

In my problem of interest I have an arbitrary, finite set $S \subset \mathbb{Z}^3$. And I would like to cover $S$ with a set $C \subset \{T | T \subset \mathbb{Z}^3 \textrm{ is an axis-aligned cube of size } \ell\}$ of minimal cardinality.

I know there exist approximation algorithms with logarithmic-ish approximation factors for the covering problem in general, but I was hoping to squeeze some extra power out of the structure I have here (having the choice of any $\ell$-sized cubes $\subset \mathbb{Z}^3$ I like, as well as having $S$ sitting on the integer lattice). But I haven't had any success. Do these restrictions give us any extra advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is NP-hard.  Fowler et al. proved it is NP-hard in two dimensions; it follows that it is NP-hard in three dimensions as well.  See the following paper:

[Optimal Packing and Covering in the Plane are NP-complete](https://fdocuments.net/document/optimal-packing-and-covering-in-the-plane-are-np-complete.html).
Robert J. Fowler, Michael S. Paterson, and Steven L. Tanimoto.
Information processing letters 12.3 (1981): 133-137.

See also [Matrix covering by squares](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/109668/755).

Comment: Awesome, though I suppose I was more hoping the extra structure allow us to achieve a better approximation factor, but skimming some papers citing Fowler, et al. I found the following paper [Approximation schemes for covering and packing problems in image processing and VLSI](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2455.214106) by Dorit S. Hochbaum and Wolfgang Maass that suggests an algorithm achieving an approximation ratio of $\leq 8$? If only it didn't look painful to implement..

Comment: @EarlyGame, it might well allow a better approximation factor: the Fowler et al result only proves that it is NP-hard to find the exact minimum.