# Binary Matrix covered with squares to cover all 1's in min cost

Tags: np-complete, dynamic-programming, matrices

So I recently came across a question in my Algorithms class.

Given a binary matrix of **N X N**.

we can do following operation any number of times

- we can take a square of size M X M (1 <= M <= N) and convert all 1's to 0's in this submatrix this operation costs M coins

we have to convert all 1's to 0's in least amount of coins.

Is this a NP-complete problem? any approach or research papers on how can this be solved?

Comment: That looks very much like this problem https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109668/matrix-covering-by-squares which is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

Comment: Also your problem cannot be $\mathsf{NP}$-complete, since it is not a decision problem.